# Commerce 3 upgrade question

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, plugin-craftcommerce3

We're about to launch a Craft Commerce 2 site. I'm wondering how involved the Commerce 3 upgrade is as far as template changes? And if we decide to upgrade now what's the best practice for making those changes? Start with the new templates and add our customizations?

Will the Stripe for Craft Commerce work with Commerce 3? I notice it just lists Commerce 2 right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commerce 3 is not a major change from Commerce 2 - you can see what you need to do to update here:

https://docs.craftcms.com/commerce/v3/upgrading.html

Stripe works with Commerce 3 without any update needed: https://github.com/craftcms/commerce-stripe/blob/develop/composer.json#L28